# Why is my navController.popBackStack() not taking me to previous screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have 4 screens **SpeechScreen1** , **SpeechScreen2**,**SpeechScreen2**, and **SpeechScreen2**. So, I am able to go to next screen from 1 to 4th screen [on right swipe gestures] and even go back [left swipe gestures]. But when I go on 4th screen, I am not able to go back to the 3rd screen even if I swipe Left. This is the code of my 3rd screen where it does go to 4th screen and also goes back to 2nd screen properly.

```
 import androidx.compose.foundation.background
    import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.absolutePadding
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
    import androidx.compose.material3.Text
    import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
    import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
    import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
    import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
    import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
    import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
    import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
    import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
    import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
    import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
    import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
    import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
    import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
    import androidx.navigation.NavController
    import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations
    import kotlin.math.absoluteValue
    
    @Composable
    fun SpeechScreen3(navController: NavController) {
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed
    
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = 69.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .padding(start = 21.dp, top = 13.dp, end = 25.dp)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTransformGestures { _, offset, _, _ ->
                            offsetX += offset.x
                            if (offsetX.absoluteValue >= swipeThreshold) {
                                if (offsetX > 0) {
    
                                    navController.navigate(Destinations.SpeechScreen4)
                                }else{
                                    navController.popBackStack()
                                }
                                offsetX = 0f
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Please read the following text:",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        lineHeight = 28.sp,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                        color = Color(0xFF000000)
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(28.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Text(
                    text ="You know,Ozma's birthday is next month,and i've been wondering what I can give her as a birthday present.She's so good to us all that we certainly ought to remember her birthday.",
                            style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 32.sp,
                    lineHeight = 40.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
                    color = Color(0xFF080808)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .padding(top = 9.dp, end = 25.dp)
                )
            }
        }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 6.dp, top = 630.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .absolutePadding(bottom = 100.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Below is the code of my 4th Screen, it doesn't go back to Screen on Left swipe gesture.

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.absolutePadding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

@Composable
fun SpeechScreen4(navController: NavController) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 69.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(start = 21.dp, top = 13.dp, end = 25.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { _, offset, _, _ ->
                        offsetX += offset.x
                        if (offsetX.absoluteValue >= swipeThreshold) {
                            if (offsetX > 0) {

//navController.navigate(Destinations.speechscreen4)
                            }else{
                                Log.d("main4", "Navigating back")
                                navController.popBackStack()
                            }
                            offsetX = 0f
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Please say the following letter four times \nA
... A ... A ... A"
                ,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(44.dp))
            Text(
                text ="Please say the following letter four times \nE
... E ... E ... E"
                ,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 6.dp, top = 630.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .absolutePadding(bottom = 100.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my Destinations object class

```
object Destinations {
    const val speechscreen1 = "speechscreen1"
    const val speechscreen2 = "speechscreen2"
    const val speechscreen3 = "speechscreen3"
    const val speechscreen4 = "speechscreen4"

}
```

Below is my NavDestinations file here I am have setup how navigation works , this is the code

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
    import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
    import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
    import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
    import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
    import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
    import com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens.SpeechScreen4
    import com.example.speechrecognition.Destinations
    import com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens.SpeechScreen1
    import com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens.SpeechScreen2
    import com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens.SpeechScreen3
    
    
    
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    @Composable
    fun NavDestinations(){
    
    
        val navController = rememberNavController()
    
        Scaffold {
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination
    =Destinations.speechscreen1){
    
                composable(Destinations.speechscreen1){
                    SpeechScreen1(navController)
                }
                composable(Destinations.speechscreen2){
                    SpeechScreen2(navController)
                }
                composable(Destinations.speechscreen3){
                    SpeechScreen3(navController)
                }
                composable(Destinations.speechscreen4){
                    SpeechScreen4(navController)
                }
    
            }
        }
    }

below is the code of my MainActivity.kt 

    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
    import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
    import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
    import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
    import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
    import androidx.compose.material3.Text
    import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
    import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
    import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
    import com.example.speechrecognition.NavDestinations.NavDestinations
    import com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens.AudioSampleRecordScreen
    import com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens.SpeechScreen1
    import com.example.speechrecognition.ui.theme.SpeechRecognitionTheme
    
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                SpeechRecognitionTheme {
                    // A surface container using the 'background' color
    from the theme
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ) {
                            NavDestinations()
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun GreetingPreview() {
        SpeechRecognitionTheme {
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use this line ```navController.navigateUp()``` instead of ```popBackStack()```

Comment: Nope, it works finely for first 3 screens , it even goes to 4th screen but it fails going back fom 4th to 3rd. It does go back from 3rd to 2nd , 2nd to 1st. I even deleted the 4th screen and created a file with diffrent name but same issue. I even deleted the 4th and only tried with 3 screens, it's working well for 3 but when I increase one more, it shows error

Comment: I solved this issue, I Column height from wrapContentHeight to fillMaxHeight()